# Overriding run list with chef zero

Tags: chef-infra, chef-zero

I have a folder "root-folder" which contains two custom cookbooks.

`- root-folder
  \
   -this-cookbook
   -that-cookbook`

I can `cd` into and run either cookbook directly

for example: `chef-client -z -o this-cookbook -j ../config.json`

Really I want to be able to `cd` into root-folder and run

`chef-client -z -o "this-cookbook, that-cookbook" -j config.json`

but that doesn't work. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options but the easiest will be to put the cookbooks in a directory called `cookbooks`.

`- root-folder
  \
   - cookbooks
    \
     -this-cookbook
     -that-cookbook`

And then run chef-client from the `root-folder`.

Reference: https://docs.chef.io/ctl_chef_client.html#run-in-local-mode

Also `-o` specifies a run-list override so your current command won't work. It will need to be something like this:

`-o 'recipe[this-cookbook],recipe[that-cookbook]'`

Reference: https://docs.chef.io/run_lists.html